# Calculating each row variance from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have file like that

```
x 1 2 3

y 6 7 9

z 9 0 0
```

ı want to read that csv files then calculate the each row of variance with np.var() using with python then ı want to rank them. T

Could you help me?

Comment: It would be very helpful of you show us what you've tried so far, so that we can help you with those parts that you have problem with or concepts that you cannot comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import csv, sys

with open("m") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header
    data = [r for r in reader]
    data.pop(0)
    print(type(data))
    a = np.asarray(data)
    print(np.nanvar(a,ddof=1))
```

I tried that it gives cannot perform reduce with flexible type error.